# Running hadoop job using java org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar command

Tags: hadoop

I want to submit a job to jobtracker using java (instead of hadoop) so that I can debug classpath issue.

```
export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=hbase-util-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:/etc/hadoop/conf:hbase-util-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/*:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/*:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/*:/usr/lib/hbase/*:/usr/lib/hadoop/etc/hadoop/mapred-site.xml:/usr/lib/zookeeper/zookeeper.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/hadoop-fairscheduler-2.0.0-mr1-cdh4.0.1.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/hbase-0.92.1-cdh4.0.1-security.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/lib/zookeeper.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/lib:/etc/hbase/conf:/usr/lib/hbase/lib/guava-11.0.2.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.5.5.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/lib/jackson-core-asl-1.5.5.jar:/usr/lib/hbase:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/*:/usr/lib/hadoop/.//*:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/./:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/*:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/.//*:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/lib/*:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/.//*:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/./:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/*:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/.//*

java -cp ${HADOOP_CLASSPATH}  org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar hbase-util-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar hbase.util.RowDiffCounter  SRM hdfs://dchilcmsnn01:8020/tmp/hadoop/mapred/temp/job1-temp-1491763074 /tmp/hadoop/mapred/temp/job1-temp-1491763075D SOURCE_MANAGEMENT  SOURCE_MANAGEMENT
```

I get an error

ERROR [main] (UserGroupInformation.java:1235) - PriviledgedActionException as:devuser (auth:SIMPLE) cause:java.io.IOException: Cannot initialize Cluster. Please check your configuration for mapreduce.framework.name and the correspond server addresses.

Adding the following properties does not help. I checked the job configuration page on the jobtracker to get the correct value.

```
 -D mapreduce.framework.name=local
 -D mapred.job.tracker=host101:8021
```

Do I need to pass in the user info as well?